# Search office documents for string python

Tags: python, string, windows, parsing, ms-office

I've been looking for a fast and relatively easy way of searching (grep-ish) for user-defined strings in files of varying formats, i.e xlsx, docx, pptx, pdf using Python.

My research has led me to believe that there might not be a convenient way of doing this, as per a single module or similar. Am I forced to use a separate module for each file type? And if so are these approriate?

docx

openpyxl

pptx

slate

I also looked at forms of decompression to get to the xml-files containing actual text but it seems unwieldy. I just want to be sure that there is no simple, uniform way of handling all of these different filetypes.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: As you've touched on parsing becomes a massive problem, Python alone may not be able solve. To be able to search efficiently also becomes quite complex. Apache Tika is a file parser with many supported formats. You could periodically cache the parsed output in a datastore (like solr) to make searching more efficient.

Comment: To follow up on your last sentence. The is no simple uniform way to parse files. As a lot of them are proprietary formats from different vendors. Docx managed by Microsoft, Pdf by Adobe, these companies don't communicate to make their file formats universal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've mostly figured it out. In the end I decided to use powershell combined with "itextsharp.dll" to process the files. It turned out to be simpler than using portable python. Thanks for the answers:-)